# How do I figure out where I am clicking on a JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, chess

I am trying to make a chess engine as a fun project, but for that I really want to make a GUI. The problem is that I have no experience with this, so I am a little stuck. I managed to create the board, but there are two things I have no idea how to do and looking online just confuses me further.

1. How do I add the pieces to the board, based on what the board looks like in the computers memory. (so for example if the engine makes a move, I want that move to also happen on the gui, how would I link the two?)
2. How do I figure out what square the user is clicking on in the gui?

This is the code I have so far for the gui, it's not much, but it's honest work

```
private final JFrame gameFrame;
    private Board board;

    public Table() {
        this.board = new Board();
        this.gameFrame = new JFrame("Chess");
        this.gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.gameFrame.setSize(527, 550);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                boolean white = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                        if (white) {
                            g.setColor(new Color(240, 217, 181));
                        }
                        else {
                            g.setColor(new Color(181, 136, 99));
                        }
                        g.fillRect(j * 64, i * 64, 64, 64);
                        white = !white;
                    }
                    white = !white;
                }
            }
        };
        this.gameFrame.add(panel);
        this.gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I know I am probably asking questions with complicated answers, but I am just looking for something I can look up or some general directions

Answer (score 0):

One way and perhaps the the most useful is to implement a `mouseListener`and then get the `x y` position from one of the methods.

- Write a class to extend `MouseAdapter`.
- override the desired empty methods.
- then add an instance of that class to the frame via `addMouseListener` (and perhaps `addMouseMotionListener`).

Then when you do some action with the mouse, you can get the coordinnates from the `MouseEvent.` It helps to put some print statements in each method to observe what is going on (what method is processing what mouse movement).

The above will serve to demonstrate the process. But later on you should actually add the listener on a `JPanel` and add the `JPanel` to the frame.